# Sample size to calculate median average for large population

Tags: sampling

I have a large dataset of individual's forename and birth year.  I'd like to know the average birth year of people with different forenames, or more specifically, how many name/year pairs do I need to be 95% confident that the median year for that name is within 1 (or 5) years of the total population with that name.

Example:

There are N=400,000 people called 'Stephen' in the total population and I know the birth year of a random sample S=22,000 of them.  The median birth year of the 22,000 is 1968 and standard deviation 10.6.

Can the minimum sample size S necessary to be 95% confident that the median over all of N is within one year of the median over S be expressed in terms of S and N?  Or within five years?

Basically I want to know for which names I have a large enough S to say what the median birth year over all of N would be, if I had everyone's birth year.  It feels intuitively that the act of taking the median should lead to the sample size being low, but I don't know how to calculate it.

(Successful answerer gets to find out the median birth year corresponding to the name of their choice!!)

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but isn't this a basic sample mean problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean

Comment: Actually that is good enough for me - it's enough to get the error down to an acceptable level. Thanks Barry (1957!)